# Can somebody explain the solution to this indefinite integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I came across this problem while I was practicing for my math exam, and I could really use someone's help...
The problem is:

$$\int\frac{1}{ax+b}\,dx$$

The solution by Symbolab and my professor is:

$$\frac{1}{a}ln|ax+b|$$

Can somebody explain why they took out the constant $\frac{1}{a}$?

Also, why is it $ax + b$ in the absolute value brackets in the solution, and not $x + \frac{b}{a}$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take derivative of the solution to see why.

Comment: It was done by substitution of $u=ax+b$

Comment: First: use $u$-substitution. Second: $\ln|x+\frac ba|$ and $\ln|ax+b|$ differ only by a constant (why?); therefore, the constant can be absorbed into the 'constant of integration'.

Answer (score 2):

Because $(\ln|x|)'=\frac{1}{x}$ and $$\left(\frac{1}{a}\ln|ax+b|\right)'=\frac{1}{a}\cdot\frac{1}{ax+b}\cdot (ax+b)'=\frac{1}{a}\cdot\frac{1}{ax+b}\cdot a=\frac{1}{ax+b}.$$

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\frac{1}{ax+b}=\frac{1}{a}\left(\frac{1}{x+\frac{b}{a}}\right)$$

Comment: I will know to use that in the future, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Note
$$(\log f(x))' = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}.$$
Since $(ax+b)' = a$, to apply the formula above you need to write
$$\int \frac{1}{ax+b} dx = \frac{1}{a} \int \frac{a}{ax+b} dx.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a bit counterintuitive for me, but I understand now